# Messages app stuck notification bubble

Tags: sms, sony-xperia, home-screen

I have had an odd problem where the [Android Messages app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging&hl=en) had a notification bubble with a number of 1 or higher. That is, the app acts as if there is one unread message. Looks kinda like this: [image: facebook icon showing one unread message]

But when I check inside the sms messages app, I see no unread messages, no unsent messages, no drafts. There shouldn't be a notification bubble. The app acts as if there's a hidden message always there.

How can I get rid of this number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP originally wrote this in the question, so I'm posting it as an answer so the question stops showing up as "unanswered":

> I dealt with this for a year or so, as it wasn't super significant, it just bugged me. I use an Xperia Z5, where Sony has their own messaging app clone, which I disabled soon after buying the phone. I used hangouts before finally switching to Android Messages, where I experienced this notification bug. To fix the problem, I simply enabled the built-in Xperia messaging app, and found a sneaky unread message: an undownloaded mms image sent to me a year ago. I deleted the message and the notification bubble went away. I went back to the Android Messages app and the notification bubble didn't come back.
>
> For those who have a pure android experience and use the default messaging app, I suggest switching to another sms app. If upon choosing said app as your default sms app, said app shows you the same ghost notification bubble, then you have a ghost message that didn't show up in the Android Messages app for some reason or other. I hope this helps a brave googler somewhere.
>
> #### tl;dr
>
> Temporarily switch to another SMS app. You may have a ghost message that isn't showing up in the app you normally use. Delete the ghost message and switch back.

Answer (score 0):

Click the 3 dots @ top right corner and MARK ALL MESSAGES AS READ.

Comment: It might be a good idea to include some screenshots to make it easier to see what you are referring to.

Answer (score -1):

I went to settings--storage and clicked Apps. Then chose messenger and clicked clear data. That removed it.